# React-on-Rails, passing and formatting props?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, events, reactjs, calendar

I'm trying to pass a collection of events objects down to a react-big-calendar component. I'm working from an example, and I'm very close - but there is something I'm missing. It is easier if I explain further with code examples:

Here is where the props are being passed in from the rails view. @events, is an array of event objects. The events will need to be formatted so they can be displayed in big calendar at some point:

```
<%= react_component("CalendarApp",
                    props: @events,
                    prerender: false) %>
```

This component is being passed to ReactOnRails.register in the following snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import Calendar from '../containers/Calendar';

export default (props) => (
  <Calendar {...props} />
);
```

Here is where 'CalendarApp' is being made available in the rails views:

```
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';
import CalendarApp from './CalendarAppClient';
ReactOnRails.register({ CalendarApp });
```

Next, is the Calendar container/smart component. The console.log(this.props) returns the following in the browser console:

[image]

**Question** How do I pass props down so that I can say something like 'this.props.events' in the following 'Calendar' component, and iterate through the list? Formatting the events so they can be passed to the MyCalendar presentation component in the correct format?

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import MyCalendar from '../components/bigCalendar';
import _ from 'lodash';

// Simple example of a React "smart" component
export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("mounted");
        console.log(this.props);
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyCalendar events={this.props}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

client/app/bundles/HelloWorld/components/bigCalendar.jsx

Ultimately I want to pass @events down to this component, my instinct is to figure out how to format the events in the container component above and pass down properly formatted events to the MyCalendar presentation component. Presently, I am using test data..which is why you see `import events from './events';`

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import events from './events';

BigCalendar.setLocalizer(
  BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment)
);

const MyCalendar = props => (
  <div className="calendar-container">
    <BigCalendar
      events={events}
      scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
      defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 12)}
      defaultView='month'
      defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 12)}
    />
  </div>
);

export default MyCalendar;
```

Comment: did you jsonify `@events` properly?console log suggests you did not

Answer (score 2):

First you need to correct you .erb react_component props

```
<%= react_component("CalendarApp",
                props: {events: @events},
                prerender: false) %>
```

Next you want to pass your this.props as a stringified object from the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state= {
       examples: JSON.stringify(this.props.examples)
    };
}
```

Something to that sort if you have an array of events using ES6 syntax you could do loop through this.state

```
 var examples = this.state
 examples = this.props.examples.map((example) => {
      return(
           <div key={example.id}>{example.name}</div>
      );
  });
```

Then you'll need to pass your newly created loop where ever you want it

```
  return(
     <div class="col-md-10">
        {examples}
     </div>
  );
```

and bam! you've got it! just remember to pass the data from your .erb controller